# How we Support Dark Mode in Current iOS App with iOS 13?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios13, ios-darkmode

My current app is developed in objC and Swift both. i need to support a darkmode. can anyone suggest how can i achieve this by globally?

Comment: take a look at UIAppearance() with a 2 struct for your colors, light and dark

Comment: in appdelegate right? or anywhere else?

Comment: It depends on the point in your code when you detects the dark/light mode. For instance how would you toogle between these two themes ?

Comment: can you provide some sample code? i just want to switching with button!

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/652-uiappearance-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Hey hi appriciate your ans. i already checked this but i am looking for some native way which provide by apple only!

Comment: Oh you are searching for a tutorial on iOS 13 darkmode am I right ?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Yup I was about to tell you to update the title but you did it. I have no knowledge on it unfortunately

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code for adding your color logic should appear in the dark mode.

```
if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {

  //Add your Dark mode colors here
 } else {

  //Your normal colors should appear here
 }
```

To know more about adapting dark mode in your iOS application please refer to the following blog post.

**[How to Adopt iOS 13 Dark Mode in your iOS App](https://www.gurutechnolabs.com/ios-13-dark-mode/)**

Answer (score 5):

There are couples of semantic system color are available in interface builder of Xcode11-beta. please use those to support both .light and .darkMode

Please follow the basics instructions step by step.

1. UIView - use systemBackgroundColor from interface builder.
2. UILabel - use defaulLabel color from interface builder.
3. CustomView - Please use .xcassests catalog and create **new color set**, add **appearances** option from **attributes inspector** for .light and .darkMode and provide different color for both mode.
4. CustomImages - Please use .xcassests catalog and add **appearances** option from **attributes inspector** for .light and .darkMode and provide different images for both mode.
5. There is also an option to provide different color and different images using code.

   ```
   override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
       super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
       updateUIForiOS13()
   }

   private func isDarkMode() -> Bool{
       if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
           let isDark = traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? true : false
           return isDark
       }
       return false
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Include the .swift file containing the UIColor extension code into your Objective-C code by utilizing the Swift Module. It can be found under **Your_Target** > **Build Settings** > **Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name**

This will generate a header file "MyApp-Swift.h"

Then add @objc to each static color function in the .swift file containing the UIColor extension code to expose it for Objective-C.

```
@objc static func color_three() -> UIColor {

    return themeConvertor(dark: "#000000", light: "#FFFFFF")

}
```

In your Objective-C .m file, import the module and then reference the color function from a UIColor extension:

```
#import "MyApp-Swift.h" // swift module

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

    // color

    textLabel.textColor = [UIColor color_three];

}
```

**Playground Example**

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {

        // color_one

        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.color_one()

        // color_two

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = UIColor.color_two()

        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view

    }

}

// put this into a file called UIColor+Extensions.swift

extension UIColor {

    static func themeConvertor(dark: String, light: String) -> UIColor {

        if #available(iOS 13, *) {

            return UIColor.init { (trait) -> UIColor in

                // the color can be from your own color config struct as well.

                return trait.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? UIColor.init(hex: dark)! : UIColor.init(hex: light)!

            }

        } else {

            return UIColor.init(hex: light)!

        }

    }

    // Color 1
    // Black & White

    @objc static func color_one() -> UIColor {

        return themeConvertor(dark: "#000000", light: "#FFFFFF")

    }

    // Color 2
    // Orange & Blue

    @objc static func color_two() -> UIColor {

        return themeConvertor(dark: "#FFA500", light: "#0000FF")

    }

    // Color from HEX

    convenience init(r: UInt8, g: UInt8, b: UInt8, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {

        let divider: CGFloat = 255.0

        self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/divider, green: CGFloat(g)/divider, blue: CGFloat(b)/divider, alpha: alpha)

    }

    private convenience init(rgbWithoutValidation value: Int32, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {

        self.init(
            r: UInt8((value & 0xFF0000) >> 16),
            g: UInt8((value & 0x00FF00) >> 8),
            b: UInt8(value & 0x0000FF),
            alpha: alpha
        )

    }

    convenience init?(rgb: Int32, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {

        if rgb > 0xFFFFFF || rgb < 0 {

            return nil

        }

        self.init(rgbWithoutValidation: rgb, alpha: alpha)

    }

    convenience init?(hex: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {

        var charSet = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines
        charSet.insert("#")

        let _hex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: charSet)

        guard _hex.range(of: "^[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil else {

            return nil

        }

        var rgb: UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: _hex).scanHexInt32(&rgb)

        self.init(rgbWithoutValidation: Int32(rgb), alpha: alpha)

    }

}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

For Colors:
[image]

```
let view = UIView()
view.backdroundColor = UIColor(named: "Color")
```

For Images:
[image]

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image")
```

Got this info from a [medium post](https://medium.com/rosberryapps/ios-13-dark-mode-29a1a601e301)