# How to adopt dark mode without loosing support for older iOS versions?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, ios13, ios-darkmode

We are supporting iOS 10 and above hence I had to use XCode 10 or else AppStore Connect gives me an error that the minimum iOS version should be 12.4 when using XCode 11. How can I adopt dark mode for newer iOS versions without losing support for iOS 10?

Comment: I have my minimum iOS version set to 9 and never got that error. Can you please post it here?

Comment: Please provide the exact error.

Comment: I have answered a similar type of question on this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679376/how-we-support-dark-mode-in-current-ios-app-with-ios-13/59030843#59030843](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679376/how-we-support-dark-mode-in-current-ios-app-with-ios-13/59030843#59030843)

Comment: @FrankSchlegel I tried reinstalling Xcode 11.2 after clearing caches and files from the library folder and somehow it worked, I can now upload a min iOS version 10 to test flight. I faced some issues after uninstalling previous Xcode and clearing Library/Developer folder but they were resolved later.

Answer (score 0):

A simple iOS version check in viewDidLoad will do:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light // example
}
```

If your user is using 13+, then display your dark mode preferences.